# scala - Get class from schema programmatically (Apache avro)

Tags: scala, maven, avro

I want to generate a scala class with getter, setter and constructor using Avro schema and mvn and not sbt.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Avro4s for this and add the following :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sksamuel.avro4s</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro4s-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>xxx</version>
</dependency>
```

For more details about using this [Avro4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s/blob/master/README.md)